# how do i cash out mined ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, coinbase

I'ved tried my luck on ethereum mining with this https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md
And I think I have some ethereum.

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase).toNumber();
5000000000000000000
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
5
```

UPDATE:
I tried to send using this but has this error:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:"0x21389ab987979ae987", value: web3.toWei(0.0005, "ether"), gas:5000})

Error: intrinsic gas too low


> eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit
5003

> net.peerCount
0
```

What is intrinsic gas too low and how to solve this, my gasLimit is 5003. What is all this and how to I would say pump more gas ?

My question is now how do I convert it to cash ? I cant figure that out. I believe on the .ethereum hidden folder contains the coinbase wallet. How do I then cash it out ?

Comment: Hi there. Ignoring the error for the moment, but are you sure you were mining on the main network and not a test network? (By February, when you posted the question, we'd already undergone the Byzantium fork, which reduced the block reward to 3 ETH. Your coinbase account has 5 ETH in it.)

Comment: how can I find that out ? You know I have 20 ETH now, thats really strange so if its true I want to cash it out. If its real, Im willing to share it off with you.

Comment: 20 is a multiple of 5, so if you've mined any of that recently, it's not going to be on the main network. What hash rate were you getting on the AWS machine? (https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator)

Comment: geth. i followed the instructions here:https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md

Comment: Okay, to be certain which network you're on, run `web3.eth.blockNumber` to get the current block number, then `web3.eth.getBlock(num).hash` using the returned number. Then check this against the hash for the block on a chain explorer. Main net: http://etherscan.io, or test nets: https://testnet.etherscan.io/ (probably Ropsten, the top one).

Comment: I can't see from those instructions how you'd connect to a testnet, but I also can't see how you'd end up with 20 ETH :-)

Comment: there seems to be some error: https://i.imgur.com/MWhccnv.png

Comment: Okay. You're being returned `4` as the latest block number. Which means your Geth instance hasn't fully sync'd the blockchain (the main net is currently on block 5,409,730). This means that the mining you've done, and the mining rewards you've earned, aren't valid, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you want to continue with this route, I'd suggest restarting Geth and waiting until the full sync of the blockchain has completed. (It can take quite a while.)

Answer (score 0):

Minimum required gas to send transaction is 21000 units. So simply use 21000 or more instead of 5000.

Comment: How to use 21k or more?

Comment: Just change gas parameter like : 

eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:"0x21389ab987979ae987", value: web3.toWei(0.0005, "ether"), gas:21000})

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you can cash out, but they will mainly depend on where you live. If you're in the states I believe you can do a deposit to your bank account through their website. Personally though I've had troubles depositing money from exchanges into my bank accounts, and have had my accounts temporarily closed due to the fraud concerns banks have with cryptocurrency. I tend to opt for sites like localbitcoins, localethereum, or even some ATMs which have low fees although that can be hard to find.

https://localbitcoins.com

https://coinatmradar.com/